# Wpf how to separate xaml.cs window logic into separate class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to **not** write all my *xaml* code into *xaml.cs* window file like- button, control, event creation etc. I would rather prefer to somehow split that logic into another class so I could implement the basic logic in many windows and append some other functionality for each specific window. So there would be no need to write all that code again and again. Is there some good approach for that?

I thought maybe it could be done with interfaces using **Dependency
injection** (*Interface injection*) accessing those functions through interface variable. I read lots of articles but didn't find any helpful information.

Comment: Take at look at MVVM pattern

Comment: [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern is what you are looking for.

Comment: With event-driven WPF you are on your own. Follow the crowd and read up on MVVM and then install the Caliburn package (Nuget). You'll end up deleting most *.xaml.cs files.

Comment: Thank you all, i will check out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have a look into MVVM: Model View ViewModel its a variation of the MVC Pattern

- Model: contains the logic and the data
- View: the GUI which shows the
  elements
- ViewModel: is the connector between model and view - it
  provides the view with methos and attributes from the Model

[Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection can also be used for preventing the hard coding of View Model in your xaml.cs
Also as suggested above MVVM is what you should go for if you're looking for nice clean and structured code.